# A regular expression to match a keyword that does not have that same word appear before another keyword

Tags: python, regex

I need to find when the word "test" appears followed by "follow", without another "test" in between.

Example:

```
test
word
word
word
test
test
word
word
follow
word
word
test
```

I only want this:

```
test
word
word
word
test
**test**
**word**
**word**
**follow**
word
word
test
```

I'm not familiar enough with regex to do this though. Any advice would be great.

**edit**
While the word test will be in there multiple times, the word follow will only be in the string once.

Comment: Please, see my answer and say me which one of the solutions of me and Ravi you find the more understandable, easy to use and fitting for your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need your regex to use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here.

```
test(?:\w|\s(?!test))+?follow
```

`(?:)` is a non-capturing group. `\w` matches any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. `\s` matches any whitespace (including new lines). `\s(?!test)` only matches a newline not followed by `test` (known as a negative lookahead in regex parlance). `()+?` just makes the match non-greedy.

*Test Input with Matches:*

```
test
word
**test**
**word**
**follow**
word
test
**test**
**word**
**word**
**follow**
word
word
**test**
**word**
**follow**
```

---

The following regex eliminates any sub-string matches as well (like test in testing, protest etc.).

```
(?<!\w)(test)\s(?!\1\s)(?:\w|\s(?!\1\s))*?(?<!\w)follow(?!\w)
```

Comment: can you explain the parts? possibly by translating your regexp to `re.VERBOSE`.

Comment: @ErikAllik, I've added the explanations. Feel free to revert if something still feels unclear to you.

Comment: But how about `test` followed by `follow` immediately, with nothing in between? Wouldn't it then have to be `*?` and not `+?`?

Comment: @ErikAllik, the regex would then match the new line `\s` between test and follow.

Comment: OK, and it seems to work with `test\nfollow\ as well, as I've just verified.

Comment: @ErikAllik, yes it would as `\s` includes `\n` as well.

Comment: Your regex pattern isn't perfect, see my answer, please.

Comment: @eyquem Thanks for bringing the sub-string issue to notice. I've pretty much fixed all the scenarios; a lot of them you've still missed too. See my comment please. :)

Comment: @RaviThapliyal You are right, I didn't think to plenty of unfavorable cases. But as you did it, it's easy to correct with llokbehind and lookahead assertions together. - Please, see my edit, in which I use a  corrected pattern in which I only use the dot ``.`` and ``\s``, this allows to analyse any strings, even the ones containing characters that ``\w`` doesn't match: your pattern fails in such cases. :)

Comment: @eyquem, the thing with regexs is that only OP would know exactly what the input looks like. So, choosing the right character class is not the real problem here. I'm sure people on SO are intelligent enough to adapt the solution to their needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally not use regular expressions here for simplicity:

```
text = (
"""test
word
word
word
test
test
word
word
follow
word
word
test
"""
)

def find_patterns(text):
    curr = []
    for word in text.split('\n'):
        if word == 'test':
            curr = ['word']  # start found sequence (also resets an existing one)
        else:
            if curr:  # if a sequence has been started by 'test'
                curr.append(word)  # otherwise just add to current sequence
                if word == 'follow':  # end of sequence
                    yield curr  # yield one result
                    curr = []  # reset sequence

print list(find_patterns(text))
```

Output:

```
 [['test', 'word', 'word', 'follow']]
```

Comment: I agree! Why go through all those contortions?

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern of Ravi produces erroneous results in some cases.
Example:

```
import re
s = """test
word 1
word 2
word 3
test 
tutulululalalo
testimony
word A
word B
follow
word X
word Y
test
"""

pat = ('test(?:\w|\s(?!test))+?follow')
print re.findall(pat,s)
#
#result : ['testimony\nword A\nword B\nfollow']
```

The pattern must be:

```
pat = ('test(?=\s)'  '(?:\w|\s(?!test(?=\s)))+?'  'follow')
print re.findall(pat,s)
#
#result : ['test \ntutulululalalo\ntestimony\nword A\nword B\nfollow']
```

Besides, I don't see the interest of the OR expression. This works:

```
pat = ('(test(?=\s)'  '(?:.(?!test(?=\s)))+?'  'follow)')
print re.findall(pat,s,re.DOTALL)
#
#result : ['test \ntutulululalalo\ntestimony\nword A\nword B\nfollow']
```

At last, I prefer the following pattern because it verifies the absence of 'test' between the beginning 'test' and the ending 'follow' in just one pass,
while `'(?:\w|\s(?!test(?=\s)))+?'` and `'(?:.(?!test(?=\s)))+?'` verify at each character if it is followed with 'follow':

```
pat = ('test(?=\s)'
       '(?!.+?test(?=\s).*?follow)'
       '.+?'
       'follow')
print re.findall(pat,s,re.DOTALL)
#
#result : ['test \ntutulululalalo\ntestimony\nword A\nword B\nfollow']
```

.

#### EDIT 1

As Ravi Thapliyal pointed it out, my last regex pattern

```
pat = ('test(?=\s)'
       '(?!.+?test(?=\s).*?follow)'
       '.+?'
       'follow')
```

isn't perfect too.
I've tried with this pattern because I never liked the pattern `(?!.(?=something))+`
My last regex pattern was supposed to replace this unliked pattern.
Well, it doesn't work, and all my efforts to make it work didn't succeed, though it seems to me that once upon a time I did use such a pattern with subtle additional parts that made it to work.
Alas, I didn't succeed, and I think I will drop the idea that it may work someday.
So I resolve to drop my ancient idea and to definitely consider that the pattern I never liked is the most evident, understandable and esay-to-write pattern.

.

Now I have a second fault to confess: I found that regex pattern of Ravi Thapliyal didn't work in some cases, but I didn't think to all the possible cases of failure.
However it's easy to correct; instead of writing `test(?=\s)` with just one lookahead assertion, I should have written `(?<=\s)test(?=\s)` with lookbehind and lookahead assertions.

Ravi Thapliyal choosed to write `(?<!\w)(test)\s(?!\1\s)` but this writing has some drawbacks:
- it must be `(?!\\1\s)` not `(?!\1\s)`
- it requires that `(test)` is defined in a capturing group , then the entire match cannot be simply listed in a `re.findall()` list or generated with a `re.finditer()` generator

He also writes `(?:\w|\s(?!\\1\s))*?`. I don't see the interest of complexifying the pattern `(?!.(?=something))+`  with an OR expression while using a dot could do the same job.

Morever, for me the most defaulting point is that the regex pattern of Ravi can't match in strings containing other characters than the ones symbolised with `\w`

For all these reasons I propose the following corrected solution:

```
import re

s1 = """test
word 1
word 2
test
word 3
tutulululalalo
protest
testimony
word
unfollow
word B
follow
word X
test
word Y
follow
"""

s2 = """test
word 1
word 2
test
word 3
tutulululalalo
protest
testimony
word ???????
unfollow
word B
follow
word X
test
word Y
follow
"""
```

.

```
# eyquem's pattern
fu = '(?<=\s)%s(?=\s)'
a = fu % 'test'
z = fu % 'follow'
pat = ('%s'
       '(?:(?!%s).)+?'
       '%s'
       % (a,a,z))

# Ravi's pattern
patRT = ('(?<!\w)(test)\s'
         '(?:\w|\s(?!\\1\s))*?(?<!\w)follow(?!\w)')


for x in (s1,s2):
    print x
    print re.findall(pat,x,re.DOTALL)
    print
    print [m.group() for m in re.finditer(patRT,x)]
    print
```

result

```
test
word 1
word 2
test
word 3
tutulululalalo
protest
testimony
word
unfollow
word B
follow
word X
test
word Y
follow

['test\nword 3\ntutulululalalo\nprotest\ntestimony\nword\nunfollow\nword B\nfollow', 'test\nword Y\nfollow']

['test\nword 3\ntutulululalalo\nprotest\ntestimony\nword\nunfollow\nword B\nfollow', 'test\nword Y\nfollow']
```

.

```
test
word 1
word 2
test
word 3
tutulululalalo
protest
testimony
word ???????
unfollow
word B
follow
word X
test
word Y
follow

['test\nword 3\ntutulululalalo\nprotest\ntestimony\nword ???????\nunfollow\nword B\nfollow', 'test\nword Y\nfollow']

['test\nword Y\nfollow'
```

]

.

#### EDIT 2

To answer precisely to the question as it is asked:

```
s = """test
word 1
word 2
test
word 3
tutulululalalo
protest
testimony
word ???????
unfollow
word B
follow
word X
test
word Y
follow
"""
fu = '(?<=\s)%s(?=\s)'
a,z = fu % 'test' ,  fu % 'follow'
pat = ('%s'
       '(?:(?!%s).)+?'
       '%s'
       % (a,a,z))

def ripl(m):
    return re.sub('(?m)^(.*)$','**\\1**',m.group())

print re.sub(pat,ripl,s,flags=re.DOTALL)
```

`ripl()` is a function used to perform the replacements, it receives each matching under the form of a RegexMatch object, and it returns the transformed part that is then used by `re.sub()` to make the replacement

Comment: Would incorrectly match on: `protest`, `unfollow`, `following` etc.

Comment: Just add `follow` at the end of input (after the last `test`) and see what happens :)